# Join three data files into a matrix having different and same time steps

Tags: linux, bash, join, awk, gawk

I have three files with data and different or same time steps. I'd like to merge them into one file or matrix using awk, join or similar as shown in the following example:

`File1.txt`

```
29.09.2016:01:10:32;4.01
29.09.2016:01:12:58;4.35
29.09.2016:01:16:01;4.52
```

`File2.txt`

```
29.09.2016:01:11:01;8.81
29.09.2016:01:15:58;9.02
29.09.2016:01:16:01;9.38
```

`File3.txt`

```
29.09.2016:01:09:01;0.56
29.09.2016:01:15:59;0.57
29.09.2016:01:16:01;0.48
```

Output: `Matrix.txt`

```
29.09.2016:01:09:01;-;-;0.56
29.09.2016:01:10:32;4.01;-;-
29.09.2016:01:11:01;-;8.81;-
29.09.2016:01:12:58;4.35;-;-
29.09.2016:01:15:58;-;9.02;-
29.09.2016:01:15:59;-;-;0.57
29.09.2016:01:16:01;4.52;9.38;0.48
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [join](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join):

```
join -a 1 -a 2 -e '-' -o auto -t ';' File1.txt File2.txt | join -a 1 -a 2 -e '-' -o auto -t ';' - File3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In Gnu awk:

```
$ cat script.awk
FNR==1 {i++}               # file counter incremented at the beginning of every file
{a[$1][i]=$2}              # set value to array using timestamp as key
END {                      # after data collection it's time to process
    for(j in a) {          # for each timestamp j
        printf "%s", j OFS # output j
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)  # for every value, print it or "-":
            printf "%s%s", (a[j][k]=="" ? "-" : a[j][k]), (k==i ? ORS : OFS)
    }
}
```

Run it:

```
$ gawk -F\; -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt 
29.09.2016:01:15:58 - 9.02 -
29.09.2016:01:15:59 - - 0.57
29.09.2016:01:10:32 4.01 - -
29.09.2016:01:11:01 - 8.81 -
29.09.2016:01:09:01 - - 0.56
29.09.2016:01:16:01 4.52 9.38 0.48
29.09.2016:01:12:58 4.35 - -
```

The output order is `gawk` random. You could control it some with `BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"}` but since it's dates we're talking about it would require conversion of the timestamp to more comparative format so the easiest would probably be to pipe the output to `sort -t\. -k3.1 -k2.1 -k1.1`.